# On mobile, how do I get "enter" to submit a form within a type="number" input?

Tags: javascript, android, html, forms, google-chrome

I'm using AngularJS and `ng-submit` like this:

```
<form ng-submit="submit(foo); foo='';">
  <input type="number" ng-model="foo">
</form>
```

In Chrome on a desktop machine, I can press enter while in the input to submit the form (which calls `submit(foo)` in this case).

In Chrome for Android (KitKat), it doesn't work.  BUT, if I change the input to `type="text"` then it *does* work when I press "Go."

How can I get the form to behave like it does for `input type="text"` with `input type="number"`?  I'm using `type="number"` because I want the device to bring up the numerical keyboard.

Here's a plunkr that illustrates the problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/4WJfdoKgXu7o6ZsM8WFx?p=preview (or http://goo.gl/IiQzGf if you're on a mobile device).

Edit:

Listening for enter with JavaScript does *not* work: http://plnkr.co/edit/07QGA1s4UCyop8IB8Dmx?p=preview

Edit 2:

It's not an AngularJS problem.  It's an HTML problem: http://embed.plnkr.co/ZVD0ZtmEutWZr7P7vq2b/preview

Answer (score 0):

I tried the last plunker (simple HTML) on Android N on a Samsung Galaxy S8, and the submit worked on both fields. It may be an issue with the specific Android version